# $G$ be an infinite group such that $|Aut (G)|=2$ , then is $G$ cyclic ?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism, infinite-groups

Let $G$ be an infinite group such that $|Aut (G)|=2$ , then is $G$ cyclic ?

Since $Aut(G)$ is cyclic here , I know that $G$ is abelian , but this is as far as I can get . Please help . Thanks in advance

Comment: (once $G$ is abelian) clearly $G$ contains $Z$. if $G \ne Z$ then it has a subgroup $H \ne Z$, and $Aut(G)$ has two distinct subgroups $Aut(H)$  and $Aut(Z)$. we are left with the case $|Aut(H)|=1$ hence $H = Z_2$ and $Aut(Z_2 \times Z)$ has $4$ elements.

Comment: @user1952009 : But how can you say that any infinite abelian group contains a copy of $\mathbb Z$ ?

Comment: What about $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$? i only see two automorphisms

Comment: @edo : isn't it generated by $1/p_i$ for each prime ? why couldn't you send only $1/p_j$ to $1-1/p_j$ ? (or even to $n/p_j$)

Comment: @user1952009: it is not generated by them. say $1/p^2$ is not in their span. Note that it would still not be enough if it were generated by them, as it is not generated freely.

Comment: @edoarad : you are right $|Aut(Q/Z)| = 2$

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ does not work. It can be decomposed as a direct sum of the groups $\cup_i ( \frac{1}{p^i}\cdot\mathbb{Z})$

Comment: @user1952009 : Okay , I am totally confused about $\mathbb Q / \mathbb Z$ ; but could you please tell me why you said in your comment that clearly $G$ contains $\mathbb Z$ ? I don't see any obvious reason why $G$ should contain an element of infinite order ..

Comment: @user1952009 : Also , if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ , how can $Aut(H)$ be a subgroup of $Aut(G)$ ? If I am not making any blunder , $Aut(H)$ is not even a subset of $Aut(G)$ ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are (infinitely generated) noncyclic torsion-free groups $G$ such that $Aut(G)\cong {\mathbb Z}/2$, see introduction to

J. T. Hallett, K.A. Hirsch, Torsion-free groups having finite automorphism groups. I. J. Algebra 2 (1965) 287–298.

and references given there (various examples are due to de Groot, Hulanicki, Fuchs, Sasiada). The paper itself discusses the question of which finite groups $A$ are isomorphic to the full automorphism group of a torsion-free group $G$.